# "Select All" Checkboxes using Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

How can I implement a "Select All" checkbox using Blazor for a collection of checkboxes? There are plenty of examples using JavaScript/jQuery, but I was trying to do it with C# instead.

Here's what I'm working with right now. This code works adding the months selected to the list, but when using the "select all" checkbox, the other boxes are not showing checked.

Note: `@Months[0].MonthName = Select All`

```
<ul class="checkbox-grid">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox"
      @onchange="EventArgs => { CheckAllMonths(Months[0], EventArgs.Value); }" />
    <label for="@Months[0].MonthId" id="checkboxLabel">@Months[0].MonthName</label>
  </li>
</ul>
@{
  for (int i = 1; i < Months.Count(); i++)
  {
    int j = i;
    <ul class="checkbox-grid">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="@Months[j].IsMonthChecked"
          @onchange="EventArgs => { CheckManualMonth(Months[j], EventArgs.Value); }" />
        <label for="@Months[j].MonthId" id="checkboxLabel">@Months[j].MonthName</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  }
}

@code {
  List<Month> MonthList = new List<Month>();

  void CheckAllMonths(Month month, object checkValue)
  {
    if((bool)checkValue)
    {
      foreach(var item in Months)
      {
        CheckManualMonth(item, checkValue);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      foreach(var item in Months)
      {
        CheckManualMonth(item, checkValue);
      }
    }
  }

  void CheckManualMonth(Month month, object checkedValue)
  {
    if((bool)checkedValue)
    {
      if(!MonthList.Contains(month))
      {
        MonthList.Add(month);
        month.IsMonthChecked = true;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if(MonthList.Contains(month))
      {
        MonthList.Remove(month);
        month.IsMonthChecked = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Initialize Months

```
  private void GetMonthChecklist()
  {
    List<Month> months = new List<Month>()
    {
      new Month{MonthId = 0, MonthName = "All Months", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 1, MonthName = "Jan", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 2, MonthName = "Feb", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 3, MonthName = "Mar", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 4, MonthName = "Apr", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 5, MonthName = "May", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 6, MonthName = "Jun", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 7, MonthName = "Jul", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 8, MonthName = "Aug", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 9, MonthName = "Sep", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 10, MonthName = "Oct", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 11, MonthName = "Nov", IsMonthChecked = false},
      new Month{MonthId = 12, MonthName = "Dec", IsMonthChecked = false}
    };

    Months = months.ToList();
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're looking for? Are you looking for a separate checkbox that can toggle other checkboxes as well?

Comment: Just did. Like I said in the updated code, the select all checkbox is adding all months to the MonthList, but the UI is not showing them checked.

Comment: Have you tried setting `month.IsMonthChecked = true` before adding it to the list?

Comment: jcruz, yes I've tried that as well, still doesn't work

Comment: In your markup you are using a `Months` variable. Where is that defined/set? The one in your code block is named `MonthsList` not `Months`

Comment: Sorry, I also have an InitializeData class that initializes the Months list. I just added it to my code

Comment: Ok great. That shows how you are populating the `Months` variable but not how/where its declared.

Comment: The component I'm using is inheriting the InitializeData class, where the GetMonthChecklist() resides. Side note, I do realize the way I'm using the CheckAllMonths method, I'm not using the 'month' parameter and probably should be.

Comment: I guess you forgot to bind the value, you bind on 'name' but name is used to create a group of radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. First, I'm sticking to the original list I created in the InitializeData class. I used @bind-Value for two-way binding and @onclick to call the methods. The CheckManualMonth method also deselects the "Select All" checkbox if another month is deselected.

```
<fieldset class="group">
    <legend>Month</legend>
    <ul class="checkbox-grid">
        <li>
            <InputCheckbox
                @bind-Value="Months[0].IsMonthChecked"
                @onclick="() => CheckAllMonths(Months[0])"/>
            <label for="@Months[0].MonthId" id="checkboxLabel">
                @Months[0].MonthName
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>

    @{
        for(var i = 1; i < Months.Count(); i++)
        {
            var j = i;
            <ul class="checkbox-grid">
                <li>
                    <InputCheckbox
                        @bind-Value="Months[j].IsMonthChecked"
                        @onclick="() => CheckManualMonth(Months[j])"/>
                    <label for="@Months[j].MonthId" id="checkboxLabel">
                        @Months[j].MonthName
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
    }
</fieldset>

void CheckAllMonths(Month month)
{
    if(month.IsMonthChecked == false)
    {
        foreach(var item in Months)
        {
            item.IsMonthChecked = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(var item in Months)
        {
            item.IsMonthChecked = false;
        }
    }
}

void CheckManualMonth(Month month)
{
    if(month.IsMonthChecked == false)
    {
        month.IsMonthChecked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        month.IsMonthChecked = false;
        Months[0].IsMonthChecked = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not bind the value to your checkbox. Actually, the easiest way to bind an input's checked attribute is to use the `InputCheckbox`:

```cs
    @foreach(var month in Months)
    {
        <ul class="checkbox-grid">
            <li>
                <InputCheckbox ValueExpression="() => month.IsMonthChecked" Value="month.IsMonthChecked" ValueChanged="() => CheckManualMonth(month)" />
                <label for="@month.MonthId" id="checkboxLabel">@month.MonthName</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be rather simple. How I implemented it in my project is like:

#### Header CheckBox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SelectAllHeader"
    @onchange="EventArgs => { CheckAllExpense(_allSelected, EventArgs.Value); }" /></th>
```

#### Body CheckBox

```
@foreach (var extExpense in _extendedExpenses)
{
    _iCount++;
    <tr class="text-sm @*row spinner-grow-sm*@">
        <td class="text-left">@_iCount</td>
        <th scope="row" @key="extExpense">
            <input type="checkbox" id="@extExpense.expense.Id" @bind="@extExpense.IsChecked" />
        </th>
    </tr>
}
```

And in the code:

```
void CheckAllExpense(bool headerChecked, object checkValue)
{
    bool isChecked = (bool)checkValue;
    _extendedExpenses.ToList().ForEach(e => e.IsChecked = isChecked);
}
```

Refer to the entire code on GitHub: https://github.com/DeepakkSHAW/ExpenseTracker.Server